# MOVUPD vs. MOVDQU (x86/x64 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

What's the difference between these instructions?  MOVDQU is an unaligned double quadword move and MOVUPD is an unaligned two 64-bit float move.  I mean they're both just moving unaligned 128-bit data.

MOVDQU is on page 948, MOVUPD is on page 995 of the intel x64 manual.

Comment: Related: [Why does the assembly use MOVUPS instruction for doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73701489) - `movups` is 1 byte smaller in machine code than `movupd`, so it's better.  ([Is there any situation where using MOVDQU and MOVUPD is better than MOVUPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40854819))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) says:

> The instructions `MOVDQA`, `MOVDQU`, `MOVAPS`, `MOVUPS`, `MOVAPD` and `MOVUPD`
>   are all identical when used with [128 bit] register operands

Then he goes on to say (he's using the aligned versions in his examples, but I'm guessing the same applies for the unaligned variants):

> On Intel Core 2 and earlier Intel processors, **some floating point instructions are executed in
>   the integer units**. This includes XMM move instructions, Boolean, and some shuffle and
>   pack instructions. **These instructions have a bypass delay when mixed with instructions that
>   use the floating point unit**. On most other processors, the execution unit used is in
>   accordance with the instruction name, e.g. `MOVAPS XMM1,XMM2` uses the floating point unit,
>   `MOVDQA XMM1,XMM2` uses the integer unit.

---

> Instructions that read or write memory use a separate unit. The bypass delay from the
>   memory unit to the floating point unit may be longer than to the integer unit on some
>   processors, but it doesn't depend on the type of the instruction. Thus, **there is no difference
>   in latency between `MOVAPS XMM0,[MEM]` and `MOVDQA XMM0,[MEM]` on current processors**,
>   but it cannot be ruled out that there will be a difference on future processors.

---

> [Y]ou may use `MOVAPS` instead of `MOVAPD` or `MOVDQA` for moving data to or from
>   memory or between registers. **A bypass delay occurs in some processors when using
>   `MOVAPS` for moving the result of an integer instruction to another register, but not when
>   moving data to or from memory**.